# Looking for a mecha fantasy anime (90's or older)

Tags: story-identification, anime

(Edit) Terribly sorry about my first post on this, I just really wanted to find the show. Anyway here's what I can remember about the show:

1. Old drawn style anime, the colours are abit bright.

2.Around the year 1990-2000.

3. It starts out in an arcade around night time.
4. The main character is a boy, maybe around 16-18 years old (Or younger) and has short black hair.
5. There are 2 girls that he met when he was sent into that world. Can't remember the other girl very much but I have a clue about the other girl. She has short light blue hair and she looks like the quiet type.
6. He has this Scanner that he uses to find robots through out the show, focusing it on every robot they face. It either shows the robots true (bad) side or true (good) side. The robots sizes are either human sized or medium (8-9 ft. Tall) and I think there was one robot that was the size of a gundam, not sure on that one.
7. The final part of the last episode shows that the boy was woken up by 3-4 other people his age, his friends. One person (a girl) reminded him of one of the girls that was with him through the show. Shocked he came close and hugged her, and that's when the credits roll in.

Comment: Roughly how old is "old"? Three years? The 80's? Could you please [edit] that in?

Comment: Terribly sorry about that, i've just been searching for it for a year or 2 now and no such luck.

Comment: Kind of makes me think of https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/MagicalShoppingArcadeAbenobashi, but only superficially.

Comment: Sadly no, but thank you for helping!

Comment: Can you give more description of the characters and what the othee world looked like. Also of the device or robots, arr they big like mechas or smaller, color, that do they do? If it was on tv,  possible tv channel.

Comment: I'll try to remember as much as I can.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Try this website. You can choose the genre of the anime and the years. Maybe the posters might refresh your memory.  https://www5.gogoanime.cloud/filter?order_by=latest&genre=50&type=series&released=1985&audio=all

Comment: Terribly sorry for the late reply, and thank you for suggesting the site! I did as you told but, to my shock, I couldn't find it. Few posters caught my attention, thought I found it but it wasn't the one I was looking for, I went as far as the 70s on my search and still found none...

Comment: Damn, I unusual find them there. Maybe is not an anime,  but another animation series from another country. Good luck finding it

Comment: Maybe, well I'll keep looking then, thanks again for the help!